# After upgrading android gradle plugin from 4.2.1 to 7.0.1 getting error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, annotations, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading android gradle plugin from 4.2.1 to 7.0.1 getting error **error: package com.android.annotations does not exist** how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Support packages have been moved to Androidx.

Follow [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) tutorial to upgrade/migrate to Androidx.

Add the correct annotation version from [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/annotation).

Also make sure, you upgraded the gradle version by version, as specified [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?buildsystem=ndk-build#updating-gradle).